# Ion Range Slider with HH:mm format From & To not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, momentjs, ion-range-slider

I am trying to use Ion Range Slider in my project to select working hours. Ex: (08:00-19:00).

```
 $('#ion').ionRangeSlider({
    grid: false,
    type: 'double',
    min: moment("0000", "hhmm"),
    max: moment("2359", "hhmm"),
    from: moment("0800", "hhmm"),
    to: moment("1900", "hhmm"),
    force_edges: true,
    drag_interval: true,
    step: 3600000,
    min_interval: 3600000,
    prettify: function (num) {
        return moment(num).format('HH:mm');
    }
});
```

When i want to set default working hours using from & to, it doesn't work. Slider works, though, but values are not changing.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using hours in milliseconds you need to change the value of **moment** you are using from an object to its milliseconds value:

```
min: moment("0000", "hhmm"),   // this is an object and not a number...
max: moment("2359", "hhmm"),
from: moment("0800", "hhmm"),
to: moment("1900", "hhmm"),
```

Change to (see docs for [details](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)):

```
min: moment("0000", "hhmm").valueOf(),
max: moment("2359", "hhmm").valueOf(),
from: moment("0800", "hhmm").valueOf(),
to: moment("1900", "hhmm").valueOf(),
```

```js
$('#ion').ionRangeSlider({
    grid: false,
    type: 'double',
    min: moment("0000", "hhmm").valueOf(),
    max: moment("2359", "hhmm").valueOf(),
    from: moment("0800", "hhmm").valueOf(),
    to: moment("1900", "hhmm").valueOf(),
    force_edges: true,
    drag_interval: true,
    step: 3600000,
    min_interval: 3600000,
    prettify: function (num) {
        return moment(num).format('HH:mm');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/master/css/ion.rangeSlider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/master/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinModern.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/master/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="ion" name="example_name" value="" />
```

Comment: Soo, that was what i've missed! I didn't notice that it was an object, and not a value. It works perfectly. Thank you!