# Can moment parse time string without date information?

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I'm wondering if moment can parse time strings only. I'm trying to format strings like '2100' which I'd like to convert to '9:00 pm'. But passing the string into moment like so:

`moment('2100').format('hh:mm a')`

...doesn't work. Neither does it work if I add the colon: '21:00'.

Ideally, I'd like it if moment could parse '2100' but I don't mind inserting the colon if necessary. What I ultimately need is for moment to parse a time string without date information. Can moment do that?

Comment: You can simply use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) passing `HHmm` as second parameter, similar examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41210785/4131048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52062005/4131048)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I try moment('2100', FORMAT) where FORMAT is 'HHmm', 'HH:mm' or 'h:mm a' and it always comes through as: Moment<2020-11-11T21:00:00-07:00>. If I say moment('2100', FORMAT).format(FORMAT), it prints out 2020-11-11 2100. If I add a date to it like so: moment('2020-11-11 2100', FORMAT) I get: Wed Nov 11 2020 21:00:00 GMT-0700... which is an improvement but still not what I want. What I want is for 2100 to be converted to 9:00 pm.

Comment: `moment('2100', 'HHmm').format('h:mm a')` shows _"9:00 pm"_, I don't fully get what is missing compared to your expected result.